# Многооконные веб-страницы

Tags: html, javascript, css, вконтакте

Добрый день! У меня к вам вопрос. Все чаще я встречаю на сайтах многооконные варианты страниц, где по нажатию какой-то ссылки выскакивает второе окно, в котором можно тоже что-то делать (например печатать текст, выбирать ссылки). При этом скроллер мыши реагирует только на главное окно, осуществляя на заднем фоне делать прокрутку страницы. С помощью чего это можно добиться? Стандартными средствами HTML+CSS или же требуется применение JavaScript?

Привожу скрин, многооконности в контакте:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Для элемента применяются стили position равные absolute или fixed. 
Изменение размера окна происходит через js и изменения свойства height и width. Аналогично перемещение окна. Свойства left и top.

Answer (score 3):

Идея следующая:

1. Создаем div на весь экран (JS + CSS), полупрозрачный (CSS), отключаем скролинг (возможно JS), позиция absolute (CSS), если мы щелкаем на нем, то выходим из этого режима, т.е. закрывается div 2 (JS)
2. Создаем div поверх 1-го div-а (JS), который вызывает ощущение 2-го окна, который можно перетаскивать (JS)

Answer (score 2):

Js нужен, без него будет тяжко.
Загляните в [jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/). Там все базовые элементы, типа диалоговых окон есть.

Comment: на русском есть что-нибудь?

Comment: http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/JQuery_UI

Answer (score 1):

Я как-то делал пример модальных окон, вот: [drag and drop html javascript](http://lampacore.ru/2013/02/18/drag-and-drop-html-javascript/)

По сути вам остается скачать плагин `mousewheel` для `jquery` и навесить обработчик события на окно.